# Google Cloud Storage + App Engine signed url upload handler

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Is there any way to create a handler with signed urls in Google Cloud Storage with Google App Engine (Java)?

I can successfully upload files to buckets with signed URLs in my Android (Java) app but I have no current way of executing additional code server-side upon upload completion.

I have been messing around with the Blobstore API and by creating upload urls that are handled by a servlet in app engine but I can't seem to make it work inside my Cloud Endpoints App Engine project.

Also, signed urls seem favorable to me because I can set expiration times on them.

Comment: There are object change notifications (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification) if you remember the signed url you created it should be possible to filter out the events you're not interested in.

Comment: @konqi Are these meant to be used in place of upload handlers in GCS?

Comment: Meant to be? I don't know. Possible: yes.

Comment: @konqi I think it was meant to be. Works like a charm. Thanks for confirming this for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the only way to do this right now is with [object change notifications](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification). Which actually isn't that bad.

I set up a servlet in my Cloud Endpoints App Engine project and in it's `doPost()` I read in the json body of the request, and parsing it you get all the information you need: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Type_AddUpdateDel

Keep in mind this warning from the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-change-notification#_Reliable_Delivery) though:

> Because of the retry mechanism above, it is possible that
>   notifications are delivered more than once. Ensure that your
>   application is idempotent with respect to processing a unique
>   notification.

So make sure whatever operations you are taking after a notification is sent is idempotent (e.g. doing the operation more than once does not affect the first result of the operation)